# Aliasing trait with associated types

Tags: rust

Is it possible to create a trait alias with specified associated types? I'm using a method from similar question [Type alias for multiple traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/alias-on-compound-type-in-rust)

```
trait Trait {
    type Item;
}

fn print<T>(value: T) where T: Trait<Item=char> {
}

trait Alias: Trait {}
impl<T: Trait<Item=char>> Alias for T {}

fn print_alias<T: Alias>(value: T) {
    print(value)
}

fn main() {
}
```

However it fails to compile with following error:

```
<anon>:12:5: 12:10 error: type mismatch resolving `<T as Trait>::Item == char`:
 expected associated type,
    found char [E0271]
<anon>:12     print(value)
              ^~~~~
<anon>:12:5: 12:10 note: required by `print`
<anon>:12     print(value)
              ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Playpen link: http://is.gd/LE4h6a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Shepmaster's solution solves the problem locally; but you would have to specify the `where T: Alias<Item=char>` each time. Alternatively, you can solve it globally by requiring that all `Alias` implements `Trait<Item=char>`:

```
trait Alias: Trait<Item=char> {}
impl<T: Trait<Item=char>> Alias for T {}
```

Which of the global or local solutions is preferred is totally up to you.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got it now: `Trait<Item=char>` in `impl` means every `Trait<Item=char>` is `Alias`, but to make every `Alias` `Trait<Item=char>`, I need same constraint in trait declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You have currently only required that all values of `Alias` must implement `Trait`, but not that the type of `Item` must be `char`. To do that you have to use the following:

```
trait Alias: Trait<Item=char> {}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I was able to understand the idea behind this after @Shepmaster explained the concept to me.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to specify the associated type in your `print_alias` method:

```
fn print_alias<T>(value: T)
    where T: Alias<Item=char>
{
    print(value)
}
```

The problem is that you've specified that every `Trait<Item=char>` also implements `Alias` (and thus `Alias<Item=char>`), but that doesn't mean that every `Alias` implements `Trait<Item=char>`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, got it working by specifying type in trait declaration: `trait Alias: Trait<Item=char> {}`