# Alias generic trait with default types

Tags: rust

I have a trait that is generic: `trait Trait<T>` and I want to create another trait that specifies the generics: `type Alias = Trait<String>`. This would allow `impl Alias for T` and not have to specify the type parameters. I tried a couple ways of doing this and haven't found any that works.

This is not a duplicate of [Type alias for multiple traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070559/155423) or [Aliasing trait with associated types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30424100/155423) because doing `trait Alias: Trait<T>` requires people to implement `Trait<T>` anyway. I want to offer a trait that hides the generics.

A clearer code sample:

```
trait DefaultEvents = Events<UserStruct, ChannelStruct, IrcStruct>;

struct MyHandler;

impl DefaultEvents for MyHandler {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've been there, and it doesn't quite answer my question. At least not to my understanding. I know about trait inheritance. Doing `trait Alias: Trait<T>` doesn't do what I want, because it requires people to implement `Trait<T>` anyway. I want to offer a trait that hides the generics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best suggestion, it's going to mean a bit more work on your part (with lots of manual trait inheritance), but it should achieve the user convenience that you want.

```
pub mod user_friendly {
    pub trait GivesNum<T> {
        fn get_num(&self) -> T;
    }

    pub trait GivesDouble {
        fn get_double(&self) -> f64;
    }

    impl<S> GivesNum<f64> for S where S: GivesDouble {
        fn get_num(&self) -> f64 { self.get_double() }
    }
}

// now your library's user needs to do less
use user_friendly::*;

struct MyStruct { num: f64 }

impl GivesDouble for MyStruct {
    fn get_double(&self) -> f64 { 2.0 * self.num }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct{ num: 5.0 };
    println!("MyStruct.get_num() = {}", s.get_num());
}
```

[Try it on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=127020a195655d5c75d90e99f08dccad&version=nightly&backtrace=0)