# Specifying associated type in trait that inherits from another trait

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types, rust-actix

I started working on my first more ambitious Rust project, and struggle with something I did not come across in any of the resources and tutorials I used for learning. The title of the question captures the abstract problem, but for the examples I'll use the concrete examples I am fighting with.

For my project, I need to interface with different third-party services, and I decided to use the [actix](https://github.com/actix/actix) framework as an abstraction for the different actors in my domain. The framework defines the `Actor` trait that must be implemented:

```
use actix::prelude::*;

struct MyActor {
    count: usize,
}

impl Actor for MyActor {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}
```

I have a trait of my own that defines the interface for the third-party integrations. Let's call it `Client`. I want each client to behave like an actor.

```
use actix::Actor;

pub trait Client: Actor {}
```

Somewhere else I have a vector that stores references to all the active clients in the system. When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Context` (from the trait `actix::actor::Actor`) must be specified
  --> transponder/src/transponder.rs:15:26
   |
15 |     clients: Vec<Box<Client>>
   |                      ^^^^^^ missing associated type `Context` value
```

I spent a few hours now attempting to solve this problem, but none of them worked.

- I tried to specify the type in the trait, but got `associated type defaults are unstable` as an error.
- I tried to specify the type in the trait's implementation (`impl Simulation`), but got `associated types are not allowed in inherent impls` as an error.
- I tried some stuff with `impl <T: Actor> Simulation for T` (e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424100/aliasing-trait-with-associated-types)), but nothing worked.

My assumption is that I am missing an important piece of knowledge about traits and types. I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve my problem, and point me in the direction of the missing puzzle piece. I feel there is an important lesson about Rust in here that I really want to learn.

Comment: FYI `Client` is not object safe, because `Actor` has a `Self: Sized` bound, so you can't use it like that, irrespective of this issue.

Comment: This is not really about trait inheritance. You would run into the same problem if there was only one trait involved. [See playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21c118974988b2d63b2c9dff873f5489)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signatures for all methods of all items in a collection must be identical, so that you can use them interchangeably. This means that the associated types of each item must be the same too.

You can get rid of this error by providing a concrete type for the `Context` associated type:

```
Vec<Box<dyn Client<Context = Context<MyActor>>>>
```

However, the code still won't work because `Actor` has a bound of `Self: Sized`, which means [it can't be made into a trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects), so neither can your trait which extends it.

Comment: `<Context = Context<Actor>` will provide the same error again you need  to define Concrete Context like <Context = Context<MyActor>. But this kills the generic approach

Comment: Ah thanks, that was a typo. But yes, this whole approach to polymorphism will not work.

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for the explanation. I remember reading this section of the book, but it didn't really click until now. I have the feeling that actix is maybe a bit too much for the beginning. I'll go with a simpler approach, until I have more experience with Rust. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As long as i understand from your code your main goal is add all Client/Actors in a collection and call it's common behavior when its needed.But due to Object Safety its not possible so we can do it with a little hack( creating trait which mimics Client, i named it as **ClientProxy**).

> I have a trait of my own that defines the interface for the
>   third-party integrations. Let's call it Client. I want each client to
>   behave like an actor.
>
> ```
> pub trait Client: Actor {}
> ```

Yes this works like that, actually this means If some struct has an implementation of Client it needs to have Actor's implementation too.

Consider we have two Context **MyActor** and **OtherActor** and their Client/Actor implementations. And we have a behavior in Client ( behave_like_client(&self) ).

```
pub trait Client: Actor {
    fn behave_like_a_client(&self);
}

struct MyActor {
    count: usize,
} 

impl Actor for MyActor {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}
impl Client for MyActor {
    fn behave_like_client(&self) {
        println!("I am MyActor as Client, and my count is {}", self.count);
    }
}

struct OtherActor {
    count: usize,
}

impl Actor for OtherActor {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}
impl Client for OtherActor {
    fn behave_like_client(&self) {
        println!("I am OtherActor Client, and my count is {}", self.count);
    }
}
```

Now we have our Actors for testing but let's go back to our problem Object Safety, we can't collect these Clients into a single collection. That's why i created `ClientProxy` to mimic `Client` and i want to implement `ClientProxy` on `Clients`. We can do this with implementing `ClientProxy` on Generics which extends Clients:

```
//ClientProxy must have all behaviors in Client 
trait ClientProxy {
    fn behave_like_client(&self);
}

//This code implements ClientProxy to all Client like Objects
impl<T> ClientProxy for T
where
    T: Client,
{
    fn behave_like_client(&self) {
        self.behave_like_client();
    }
}
```

Now everything is ready, we can test our structure:

```
struct Container {
    clients: Vec<Box<ClientProxy>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container {
        clients: Vec::new(),
    };
    let a = Box::new(MyActor { count: 3 });
    let b = Box::new(OtherActor { count: 4 });

    container.clients.push(a);
    container.clients.push(b);

    container
        .clients
        .iter()
        .for_each(|a| a.behave_like_client());
    //output : 
    //I am MyActor as Client, and my count is 3
    //I am OtherActor Client, and my count is 4
}
```

You can reach the full code from [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09125e4d5132401f26b942c14ae7c370) ( it's not running on playground due to lack of dependency )

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is an interesting approach that might come in handy in the future.

Comment: It should be noted this only works if you have methods on `Client` that don't rely on any types like `Context` or anything in `Actor`. You can pretty much only take `&self` by reference and call a method.