# Storing Structs with same Trait and different Output Type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store different structs with a common trait in a `Vec<Box<dyn ...` collection.
It seems to be difficult, as the `impl Trait for Struct` has different output types.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ef7bf3ab6486ef62817268cc311379b)

```
fn main()
{
    let p = TheirPoint ...
    let l = TheirLine ...
    let vec_shapes: Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow>> = vec![Box::new(l), Box::new(p)];
}

impl TheirShadow for TheirPoint {
    type Output = (TheirPoint, TheirPoint);
...
}

impl TheirShadow for TheirLine {
    type Output = (TheirPoint, TheirPoint, TheirPoint, TheirPoint);
...
}

pub trait TheirShadow {
    type Output;
...
}
```

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Output` (from trait `TheirShadow`) must be specified
  --> src/main.rs:32:33
   |
32 |     let vec_shapes: Vec<Box<dyn TheirShadow>> = vec![Box::new(l), Box::new(p)];
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `TheirShadow<Output = Type>`
...
73 |     type Output;
   |     ------------ `Output` defined here
```

Can this be achieved, or is it similar like in another questions answer, that [The signatures for all methods of all items in a collection must be identical, so that you can use them interchangeably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53805548/5011027)?

Comment: How will you use `vec_shapes`? If you can't know the type of `Output`, you wouldn't be able to use any functions that rely on that type, at a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know `Output`, you can't actually use the functions that return `Output`, due to the fact that they're all different sizes, and Rust can't know which one is being returned. The easiest way to fix this is to use an enum:

```rust
enum Shadow {
    Tuple2(TheirPoint, TheirPoint),
    Tuple4(TheirPoint, TheirPoint, TheirPoint, TheirPoint)
}

impl TheirShadow for TheirPoint {
    type Output = Shadow;
    fn cast_shadow(self) -> Self::Output {
        Shadow::Tuple2(some_point, some_other_point)
    }
}

// and so on
```

You could even eliminate the `Output` type and just force a return value of `Shadow` in the trait.

Comment: sounds good! Problematic is, that 'Their' elements aren't written here. Is there a way to map that? With a parent trait possibly? Match TheirPoint::Output?

Comment: Can you be more detailed with what you want to do?