# Is there a way to signal that an impl trait type also implements additional traits?

Tags: types, rust

I have a function that returns an impl trait:

```
pub fn new(buf: &[u8]) -> Result<impl Temperature, u8>
```

Is there a way to signal that the underlying struct also implements `Debug` (via `#[derive(...)]`), so I can format the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, combine multiple traits with a `+`, just like in trait bounds:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Foo {}

fn new() -> impl Foo + Debug {
    Dummy
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Dummy;
impl Foo for Dummy {}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", new());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to give a single name to a set of traits? In short: can I return "Cake" instead of "Dough + Chocolate"?

Comment: Yes. See [Type alias for multiple traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070559/155423)