# How to give a reusable name to a ?Sized multiple type bound in a Rust generic function

Tags: generics, rust

Take the following code

```rust
fn do_stuff<T: ?Sized + io::Write + io::Read>(mut serial: Box<T>) {
  // stuff
}
```

It can take for example a serial device to work with, or maybe a file for testing purposes. This works, but writing that type bound is quite a handful.

How can I give a name for the bound that I can reuse in other functions? Using (as per [Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits))

```
trait IoDev : io::Write + io::Read {}
impl<T: io::Write + io::Read> IoDev for T {}
```

solves the issue partially, as there's no need to repeat `Write+Read` anymore, but I still have to repeat `?Sized` on each function. Is there a way to get out of repeating that too?

Comment: What is the problem with writing new trait for that? Imho, It seems good declaring a new trait for such case

Comment: I don't mind declaring a new trait, I just couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Ömer I don't see how that question+answers would help me.

Comment: for `trait IoDev  : Write + Read{}`  this `impl<T: Write + Read> IoDev for T {} `, then use it like `fn do_stuff<T:IoDev>`

Comment: that's what the Q&A points

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is that the trait is not automatically implemented. Even when a type fulfills all preconditions for a trait, you have to manually write the `impl` for it. The compiler does not do it automatically because implementing a trait may give it some new meaning.

For example, the `std::iter::FusedIterator` trait has no methods or associated types and the only requirement is that the implementing type is an `Iterator`. The compiler must not implement it automatically, because it  carries special meaning and the programmer must decide whether it should be implemented for their specific iterator or not.

If you want to implement your trait for every type that fulfills the conditions, you can do a blanket implementation:

```rust
trait IoDev : io::Write + io::Read {}

impl<T: io::Write + io::Read> IoDev for T {}
```

Comment: If I add `?Sized` to both the `impl` line and the function declaration, then this works. Is there no way to get that out too?