# Type aliasing for multiple traits with generic types

Tags: types, rust

My question is similar to the one addressed in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits).

I'm trying to make a generic vector struct and I have the following working:

```
use std::ops::{Add, Sub};

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vec2<T> where 
    T: Add<Output = T> + Sub<Output = T>
{
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T> Vec2<T> where
    T: Add<Output = T>  + Sub<Output = T>
{
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Vec2<T> {
        Vec2 { x, y }
    }

}

// Overload `+` operator for Vec2
impl<T> Add for Vec2<T> where
    T: Add<Output = T>  + Sub<Output = T>
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

// Overload `-` operator for Vec2
impl<T> Sub for Vec2<T> where
    T: Add<Output = T>  + Sub<Output = T>
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn sub(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x - other.x,
            y: self.y - other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, this `Add<Output = T> + Sub<Output = T>` bound is a little messy, especially if I plan to implement more traits. Is there some way to use macros or type aliasing to so I can do something along the lines of:

```
trait Num: Add + Sub {}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vec2<T> where 
    T: Num
{
    ...
}

// Overload `+` operator for Vec2
impl<T> Add for Vec2<T> where
    T: Num
{
    ...
}
```

Note: Understandably, the code above produces a compilation error. If you look at the documentation for either the [std::ops::Add](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) or [std::ops::Sub](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html) traits, they have a default generic type `<Rhs = Self>` whose size cannot be determined at compilation time, so I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even possible. But it would be nice if there was some workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trait you are looking for can be found in [num-traits](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.11/num_traits/trait.NumOps.html) crate:

```rust
pub trait NumOps<Rhs = Self, Output = Self>:
    Add<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Sub<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Mul<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Div<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Rem<Rhs, Output = Output>
{
}

impl<T, Rhs, Output> NumOps<Rhs, Output> for T where
    T: Add<Rhs, Output = Output>
        + Sub<Rhs, Output = Output>
        + Mul<Rhs, Output = Output>
        + Div<Rhs, Output = Output>
        + Rem<Rhs, Output = Output>
{
}
```

You can easily use it in your vector type:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vec2<T: NumOps> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T: NumOps> Add for Vec2<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

[Full code in playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0d095c6a17fa8392dd03c4ff43b9ff5)

But actually it is a better practice to narrow down every trait bound to the very minimum:

```rust
// No trait bound on T: Vec2 can store any type
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vec2<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T> Vec2<T> {
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T) -> Vec2<T> {
        Vec2 { x, y }
    }

}

// Implement `+` operator for Vec2<T> only if T has it
impl<T> Add for Vec2<T>
    where T: Add<T, Output = T>
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

// Implement `-` operator for Vec2<T> only if T has it
impl<T> Sub for Vec2<T>
    where T: Sub<T, Output = T>
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn sub(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x - other.x,
            y: self.y - other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

[Full code in playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d4fc29ed38a129faac871eae4dc0de4)

This way, Vec2 can be constructed with any possible type, but `Add` is implemented only if `T` has corresponding `Add`; same for `Sub`.