# How to shorten a long where clause?

Tags: generics, rust

I have this declaration:

```rust
impl<T: JobContext, R> TaskProcessor<T, R>
where
    R: hyper::service::Service<hyper::client::connect::dns::Name> + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
    R::Response: std::iter::Iterator<Item = std::net::SocketAddr>,
    R::Future: Send,
    R::Error: std::error::Error + Send + Sync,
{
}
```

I want to move the condition after `where` into its own trait so I could write something like:

```
impl<T: JobContext, R: DnsResolve> TaskProcessor<T, R> { }
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070559/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I'd also mention that long `where` clauses are part of the job, and you get used to them pretty quickly. Unlike in Java where type signatures are primarily a chore, in Rust you'll find that they actually communicate useful information and contribute to readability.

Comment: I don't mind long declaration in one place, thing is I have nested types which kinda passthrough this `TaskProcessor` type(and it's `R`)... and rust won't allow me to compile unless I drag this long declaration in all of my types that use `TaskProcessor`. Copy-paste is bad

Comment: @Shepmaster my where clause has nested trait types(`Response`, `Future`, `Error`) defined inside `hyper::service::Service` and I have no idea how to reference them in a new trait. I would be very grateful for example...

Comment: One easy way is to import the items into scope.

Comment: @let4be You should be able to use the same `where` clause as in your original code, just with `Self` instead of `R`. `trait X: Y {}` is equivalent to `trait X where Self: Y {}`.

Comment: So how would I define the `DnsResolve` trait? Nothing I've been trying to do so far compiles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem

```
trait DnsResolve: hyper::service::Service<hyper::client::connect::dns::Name, Response: std::iter::Iterator<Item = std::net::SocketAddr>, Future: Send, Error: std::error::Error + Send + Sync> + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static
{
}

impl<T> DnsResolve for T where T: hyper::service::Service<hyper::client::connect::dns::Name, Response: std::iter::Iterator<Item = std::net::SocketAddr>, Future: Send, Error: std::error::Error + Send + Sync> + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
}
```

But this uses unstable feature

https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2289-associated-type-bounds.html

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662

And I had to compile my code using nightly rustc... which I don't really like

This topic is quite complicated for me, is there any way around the associated type bounds in stable rust?