# Is dyn A+B possible?

Tags: rust

I have a custom socket that implements `AsyncWrite` and `AsyncRead`. I'd like to store a dyn to this socket, but I'd like to use both `AsyncWrite/Read`, like this:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct AsyncTransporter {
    stream: Arc<dyn AsyncRead + AsyncWrite>,
}
```

but this is not supported.

```
60 |     stream: Arc<dyn AsyncRead + AsyncWrite>,
   |                     ---------   ^^^^^^^^^^ additional non-auto trait
   |                     |
   |                     first non-auto trait
   |
   = help: consider creating a new trait with all of these as super-traits and using that trait here instead: `trait NewTrait: tokio::io::AsyncRead + tokio::io::AsyncWrite {}`
```

If I do `trait NewTrait: tokio::io::AsyncRead + tokio::io::AsyncWrite {}`, how will the methods of both traits be implemented?

Comment: [Is there any way to create a type alias for multiple traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I do `trait NewTrait: tokio::io::AsyncRead + tokio::io::AsyncWrite {}`, how will the methods of both traits be implemented?

`trait NewTrait: tokio::io::AsyncRead + tokio::io::AsyncWrite {}` requires implementors of `NewTrait` to first implement `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite`, so if you have a type that implements `NewTrait`, you can count on `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite`'s methods just being there. Thus it's not so much a question of "how will the methods of both traits be implemented", but of "how will `NewTrait` be implemented for an arbitrary type that implements `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` and knows nothing of `NewTrait`?"

The response is, by providing a *blanket implementation* of `NewTrait` for all types that implement the two:

```
impl<T> NewTrait for T
where
    T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite
{
}
```

With that implementation, *any* type (even one defined in another crate) that implements both `AsyncRead` and `AsyncWrite` also implements `NewTrait`.

Comment: I tried this and called the new trait `AsyncRW` but I get `self.stream.poll_read(cx, buf)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Arc<(dyn AsyncRW + 'static)>``

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Maybe the problem is that `poll_read()` requires `&mut self`, so it won't work through an Arc?

Comment: Indeed. What should I do then? `Arc<Mutex<>>` is not good as it would block inside `poll_read`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs There are async mutexes that are acquired via an async fn, e.g. [this one](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html). That seems outside the scope of this question, though.