# Creating an alias for a Fn trait results in "one type is more general than the other" error

Tags: rust

I learned [an idiom to give an alias to trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070559/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-type-alias-for-multiple-traits). But, when I applied this idiom to my code, I encountered a puzzling error.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```rust
// `StrToStr` is an alias for `Fn(&str) -> &str`
trait StrToStr: Fn(&str) -> &str {}
impl<T> StrToStr for T where T: Fn(&str) -> &str {}

// A function that returns `StrToStr`
fn identity() -> impl StrToStr {
    |s: &str| s
}
```

When I compile this code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:77:18
   |
77 | fn identity() -> impl StrToStr {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected reference `&str`
              found reference `&str`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `rust-calc` due to previous error
```

After trying several times with different return types, this error seems to occur when returning a reference type. However, I do not know why this error occurs and how to avoid it.

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to explain what's going on, but if you write out the lifetimes it does compile: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fb5daa4057f9328b7e6fb5fd5d4f94ae

Comment: This is not the automatic desugaring. The automatic desugaring is like `trait StrToStr: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str {}`

Comment: @IvanC Thank you for the information. It's interesting that it can compile if you give it a lifetime. However, the type after adding the lifetime is different from the original type. The original type is `trait StrToStr: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str {}`, as Chayim Friedman says.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman so the problem is that `impl StrToStr` implies that the closure would work for any lifetime `'a` but it actually only works for one concrete `'a`?

Comment: I found that removing the type annotation for `s` in `identity` function improved the error message. The message clearly states that `expected type for<'r> Fn<(&'r str,)>, found type Fn<(&str,)>`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that lifetime desugaring differs for closures and trait bounds, since this also compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e66d704d54bd434f13bfb856c91941f

Comment: @IvanC Oh, that's nice! But why do we need explicit type annotations here?

Comment: It works if we specify the type explicitly even if we don't desuagr manually ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac1675719e070d3347c88c30ae8e3fdf)). I suspect the reason is like @YusukeNOJIMA said, that closures aren't generic over lifetimes. But what bothers me is that if you treat them as function pointers it works. I don't have enough time to dig into that now.

Comment: Really strange: it errors without a trait too ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=043ff7c3611a365dd6fdaf816a5b1751)), but without it, if you remove the temporary binding it compiles: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7eb28c89699c1db2785dc8008ae08ae).

Comment: According to this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=701fad877aebd7d0c8d3373df812ca4c) error message, binding a closure to a variable seems to lose the lifetime quantification. The type of the expression `|s| s` seems to be `for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str`, but the type of the variable `ret` seems to be `Fn(&'b str) -> &'b str` for **some** 'b.

Comment: @YusukeNOJIMA The other way around: the return type is `for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str`, but the closure `|s| s` (and thus the type of `ret`) has the type `Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str` for some lifetime `'a`. This is well-known that regular lifetime inferrence rules does not apply to closures. My only question is why it works if we specify the type, and why the compiler doesn't infer the type from the return type if it's possible to convert.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Mmm... This seems to be beyond my understanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [a work-around for this problem in a GitHub discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70263#issuecomment-623169045). First, we define a no-op function to help in the type inference of the closure.

```rust
fn generalize_lifetime<F>(f: F) -> F
where
    F: Fn(&str) -> &str,
{
    f
}
```

Then, wrap the closure with `generalize_lifetime` and the compilation will pass.

```rust
// `StrToStr` is an alias for `Fn(&str) -> &str`
trait StrToStr: Fn(&str) -> &str {}
impl<F> StrToStr for F where F: Fn(&str) -> &str {}

// A function that returns `StrToStr`
fn identity() -> impl StrToStr {
    generalize_lifetime(|s| s)
}
```